# Как сделать распараллеливание программы на GPU с использованием OpenAcc?

Tags: c++, gpu, opencl

```
for (int y = m; y < d; y++) {
    float local_sim = 0;
    for (int x = m; x < k; x++) {               
        local_sim += func(x, y);
    }
    similarity += local_sim;
}
```

Как правильно сделать это? При компиляции делаю так:
`g++ -std=c++0x   /* ... */   -fopenmp -fopenacc`

Перед данным циклом поставил `#pragma acc parallel` - но ничего не работает. Компилится все без проблем, но работает в 1 CPU ядро.

В самом начале  заголовки подключил `#include` 
C openmp использовал что-то вроде этого: `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:similarity) num_threads(use_threads)`
Как заставить это пахать юзая GPU? Спасибо!

Comment: в теме Вы пишете "распараллелить на **GPU**",  а жалуетесь, что работает только на одном ядре **CPU**. Это же очевидно.

Comment: @KoVadim так я говорю о том что мне нужно обеспечить работу на GPU, а #pragma от ACC не работает, вот как ее настроить меня интересует.

Comment: а вот этого мы не знаем. может оно и грузит gpu.надо смотреть, грузит ли оно gpu. А cpu при этом может и не грузится

Comment: @KoVadim как лучше всего это делать, у меня Ubuntu 17.04?  Просто задача выполняется очень долго, и я прикинул что все считается на gpu (прироста в производительности нет вообще, ну по времени)

Comment: думаю, надо начать с этого https://docs.computecanada.ca/wiki/OpenACC_Tutorial_-_Optimizing_loops (там есть ссылка на то, что есть профайлер от nvidia, который поможет)

Comment: Я видел, у меня кстати  amd, пробовал не помогло

Comment: Кстати вот [методичка](http://www.nvidia.ru/docs/IO/130383/OpenACC.pdf), где на удивление хорошо разобраны основные скользкие моменты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поддержка [OpenACC](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/OpenACC) в gcc пока в экспериментальном состоянии. На данный момент(gcc-7.2) формально поддерживыется спецификация OpenACC-2.0a с двумя backend'ами: fallback для обычного выполнения в один поток на CPU и для устройств NVIDIA, nvptx. Последний требует отдельной самостоятельной (можно уже в принципе найти и пакеты) сборки двух компиляторов: разгрузочного([offloading](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Offloading)), который генерирует ассемблерный код nvptx, и [пере]сборка хостового с поддержкой разгрузки. Пока что поддерживается генерация кода только для sm30(CUDA-3.0) (старшие версии обратно совместимы). В экспериментальной ветке ведётся работа над поддержкой sm35.

На сколько я знаю, единственным полноценным компилятором на сегодня для OpenACC является проприетарный [PGI](http://www.pgroup.com/). Правда, если верить [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44283009/openacc-compiling-with-amd-gpus), поддержку AMD из последних версий выкинули, так что придётся пользоваться веткой 16.x.

Код в первом приближении будет такой же простой, как и для OpenMP:

```
#pragma acc parallel loop reduction(+:similarity)
for (int y = m; y < d; y++) {
    float local_sim = 0;
    for (int x = m; x < k; x++) {               
        local_sim += func(x, y);
    }
    similarity += local_sim;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Т.е на amd, даже если будет параллелизм все будет на CPU выполняться??

Comment: @EKRE, если найдёшь компилятор, который будет генерировать код для amd карт, то он будет выгружен на GPU. Про то что старых версий PGI нет в открытом доступе я судя по всему [наврал](http://www.pgroup.com/support/download_pgi2016.php). И да, реальный директивы необходимые чтобы получить хороший прирост производительности будут, вероятно, сложнее...